# Bootstrap nav links way out of place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have a navbar (using bootstrap 4 css), I have 3 links and a brand.

I expect all of these to be in line but for some reason they are all over the place.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

And here is my current code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- Toggle Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content">
    ☰
  </button>

  <!-- Nav Content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="nav-content">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#search">Search <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-right pull-md-right pull-lg-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-center">Play button will go here when video is implemented</p>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Earn now! &raquo;</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using proxima nova as my font and yeah, never had this happen before, any ideas?

Comment: Instead of image please post the code directly here.

Comment: done, added to the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
I have added pull-md-left class to first navbar-nav.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">

  <!-- Toggle Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler hidden-sm-up" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-content">
    ☰
  </button>

  <!-- Nav Content -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-toggleable-xs" id="nav-content">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-md-left">
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="#search" class="nav-link">Search <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-sm-right pull-md-right pull-lg-right">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Log In</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>

<!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-center">Play button will go here when video is implemented</p>
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Earn now! &raquo;</a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use `nav-item` and `nav-link` in the Search link...

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#search" class="nav-link" >Search <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      </li>
  </ul>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/QYgdMWVyki

Also, at this time Bootstrap 4 is in alpha so it's a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use a single 'ul class="nav navbar-nav" ' for your navbar and put class' "pull" directly on your 'li' tags? :)

Comment: Yeah, but it doesnt work in bs4, atleast from what I saw when I tried that.

there are a load of new pull classes now.

And besides, I need 2 because one is for the left and one for the right, you know?